# laravel5.8 Queue::exceptionOccurred get an exception

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

When I use function queue on laravel5.8, I want to listen an event **Queue::exceptionOccurred**

so i register it on `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider`

```
/**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {

        //exceptionOccurred
        Queue::exceptionOccurred(function (JobFailed $event) {
            Log::info('exception occurred',[
             $event->connectionName,
             $event->job,
             $event->exception]);
        });
    }
```

and then, when I fire this event, I get some exception:

```
[2019-12-15 10:15:38] local.ERROR: Argument 1 passed to App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::App\Providers\{closure}() must be an instance of Illuminate\Queue\Events\JobFailed, instance of Illuminate\Queue\Events\JobExceptionOccurred given, called in /Users/jinmi/www/php/laravel_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php on line 347 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Argument 1 passed to App\\Providers\\AppServiceProvider::App\\Providers\\{closure}() must be an instance of Illuminate\\Queue\\Events\\JobFailed, instance of Illuminate\\Queue\\Events\\JobExceptionOccurred given, called in /Users/jinmi/www/php/laravel_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php on line 347 at /Users/jinmi/www/php/laravel_test/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php:38)
[stacktrace]
#0 /Users/jinmi/www/php/laravel_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(347): App\\Providers\\AppServiceProvider->App\\Providers\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Events\\JobExceptionOccurred))
#1 /Users/jinmi/www/php/laravel_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(196): Illuminate\\Events\\Dispatcher->Illuminate\\Events\\{closure}('Illuminate\\\\Queu...', Array)
#2 /Users/jinmi/www/php/laravel_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(493): Illuminate\\Events\\Dispatcher->dispatch('Illuminate\\\\Queu...')
#3 /Users/jinmi/www/php/laravel_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(373): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->raiseExceptionOccurredJobEvent('database', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\DatabaseJob), Object(ErrorException))
#4 /Users/jinmi/www/php/laravel_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(341): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->handleJobException('database', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\DatabaseJob), Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\WorkerOptions), Object(ErrorException))
#5 /Users/jinmi/www/php/laravel_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(283): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->process('database', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\DatabaseJob), Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\WorkerOptions))
#6 /Users/jinmi/www/php/laravel_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(118): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->runJob(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\DatabaseJob), 'database', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\WorkerOptions))
#7 /Users/jinmi/www/php/laravel_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(102): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->daemon('database', 'default', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\WorkerOptions))
#8 /Users/jinmi/www/php/laravel_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(86): Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->runWorker('database', 'default')
#9 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->handle()
#10 /Users/jinmi/www/php/laravel_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(32): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 /Users/jinmi/www/php/laravel_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(90): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#12 /Users/jinmi/www/php/laravel_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(34): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#13 /Users/jinmi/www/php/laravel_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(576): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#14 /Users/jinmi/www/php/laravel_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(183): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#15 /Users/jinmi/www/php/laravel_test/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#16 /Users/jinmi/www/php/laravel_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(170): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#17 /Users/jinmi/www/php/laravel_test/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(915): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#18 /Users/jinmi/www/php/laravel_test/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(272): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#19 /Users/jinmi/www/php/laravel_test/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(148): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#20 /Users/jinmi/www/php/laravel_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(90): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#21 /Users/jinmi/www/php/laravel_test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(133): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#22 /Users/jinmi/www/php/laravel_test/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#23 {main}
"}
```

Should I set something on this project to fix this exception?

Comment: but your code is not good 
Why did you add  Queue::exceptionOccurred to boot method?? !!!!

Answer (score 0):

change like this

```
/**
* Bootstrap any application services.
*
* @return void
*/
public function boot()
{

    //exceptionOccurred
    Queue::exceptionOccurred(function (Illuminate\Queue\Events\JobExceptionOccurred $event) {
        Log::info('exception occurred',[
        $event->connectionName,
        $event->job,
        $event->exception]);
    });
}
```

Comment: probably want to throw a "\" in front of that FQCN so it doesn't reference it as `App\Providers\Illuminate\Queue\....`